# Android Material EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-support-design

I'm using `Support Design Library`. I created `EditText` but when I'm writting something there is some blue underline of edit text like in the picture below

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Test"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems autocomplete/suggestions are open. Try this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Test"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:singleLine="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```